# If set $C$ is recursively enumerable and $B$ is Recursive, and if $B-C$ is recursively enumerable then is $C$ recursive or not?

Tags: turing-machines, computability, undecidability, recursion

So this is how i solve it but someone told me its wrong:

$B-C = B\cap \overline C $ and since $B\cap \overline C $ is r.e and B is recursive recursive sets are closed under intersection then $\overline C $ is not Recursive(because if both of them were recursive then the intersection would be recursive), also since r.e sets are closed under intersection then $\overline C $ must be r.e

and since $\overline C $ and $C$ are r.e then C is recursive

so am i wrong? is C recursive or not and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument is wrong.

Your argument is: $B\cap \bar C$ is r.e., $B$ is recursive, so $\bar C$ has to be non recursive, otherwise $B \cap \bar C$ would be recursive -- contradiction.

However, there is no contradiction: $B\cap \bar C$ *can* be both r.e. and recursive. This is equivalent to $B\cap \bar C$ being recursive. There is no hypothesis contradicting that.

Indeed, take $C$ to be the halting problem (r.e., and not recursive). Take $B=\emptyset$ which is recursive. Then $B\cap\bar C = \emptyset$ which is (recursive and) r.e. . So all the hypotheses are satisfied, but $C$ is not recursive.

Comment: So is C not recursive? how can i prove it i can't come up with anything

Comment: That specific $C$ is, so we can't conclude that $C$ is recursive, in general. (I am not implying here that every $C$ satisfying the hypothesis must be non recursive. For this I don't need a general proof, only a counterexample)

Comment: But how can i prove that C is in fact not recursive?

Comment: What makes you think you can prove that? Try to find a counterexample. From those hypotheses you can't conclude either C recursive not C not recursive. They are too weak to conclude something.

Comment: But my teacher says i can!! this question was on our exam and he says we can prove that C is not recursive

Comment: Taking $B=C=\emptyset$ satisfies all the hypotheses, but does not make $C$ recursive. I'd guess one of this must be the case: 1) you have some other hypothesis, 2) your teacher is actually saying "you can not conclude that C is recursive" instead of "you can conclude that C is not recursive", 3) either me or your teacher is wrong.

Comment: My bad, i rechecked the question and $B-C$ is equal to the halting set, so its not just any  recursively enumerable set. and therefore both of them cannot be NULL

Comment: @JohnPence That changes the question significantly. Perhaps it's better if you open another question (which also would give the problem more visibility)